# Drop down selection issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown and its being populated correctly by three recordes d1, d2, d3 and their values are 0,1,2

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Distance" class="col-md-3">
                        Distance :
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="Distance" name="Distance" class="form-control selectwidthauto" ng-model="ModelData.Distance" 
                    ng-options="distance.Code as distance.Description for distance in DropdownData.Distances">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Why the dropdown selection is not working whereas I am getting the value of {{ModelData.Distance}} as 2 on the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf to check the iteration number. This will help you to identify the specific iteration that is selected.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="app">
    <select 
          ng-model="item"
          ng-options="values.indexOf(item) as item for item in values"></select>
    item: {{item}}
</div>

function app($scope) {
    $scope.values = ["Value1","Value2"];
    $scope.item= 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use indexOf? Its working for the other dropdowns on the page.

Comment: No. Not any specific reason. But since there is no way to note iteration in ng-options like we can use $index in ng-repeat so it provides a handy tool.
For your case you have to post your full code for detailed analysis.
You can give plunker link for your code.

Comment: ok. but I can not use indexOf as my model is containing ID not the value.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me but I don't know how it is binding on controller side. So can you give full code or place your code on JSfiddle or Plunker to analyze?